# How to access parent page controls in usercontrol in silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-8

I want to access the mainpage grid values in user control (child page).Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you use Model-View-ViewModel pattern or are your data stored in page/control code-behind?

Comment: i am not using MVVM Model.using normal pages code only

Answer (score 0):

You may expose your `MainPage` on the `App` class (declared in `App.xaml.cs`) as `App.MainPage` property:

```
public MainPage MainPage { get; private set; }

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    this.MainPage = new MainPage();
    this.RootVisual = this.MainPage;
}
```

Then you can access all exposed properties/functions on the MainPage class as follows:

```
MainPage mainPage = ((App)App.Current).MainPage;
```

Alternatively you could find MainPage in visual tree of the page as follows:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;


// place this code where you want to find MainPage
MainPage mainPage = this.GetVisualAncestors().OfType<MainPage>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Which way does not work from the samples, the first or the second?

Comment: in windows 8 there is no application_Startup event.i am not able to write this in windows 8 app.xaml.cs page.Have you idea on windows 8 apps?

Comment: Are you developing Windows 8 WPF or Silverlight app under Windows 8? Because your question title says "in Silverlight"... Anyway, you could also try the second option with visual tree. If you are concerned about the performance, store the value for next usage in the class field.